# Frida and Android Keyboard questions

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I recently tried using Frida to hook keyboard events when a key on the in screen (software?) keyboard. I have tried hooking the following and displaying the values

- android.app.Activity

  - onKeyUp
  - onKeyDown
- android.view.KeyEvent

  - getKeyCode
  - keyCodeToString
- android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager

  - dispatchKeyEventFromInputMethod

I noticed that only certain key presses caused the functions to be called. For example, if I pressed an alphabet, the functions do not get triggered but when I pressed a number, it gets displayed.

Just curious if that's the default behaviour of Android or am I hooking the wrong class?